# Null-Coallescing Operator - Why Casting?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, nullable, null-coalescing-operator

Can anyone please tell me why does the first of the following statements throws a compilation error and the second one does not?

```
NewDatabase.AddInParameter(NewCommand, "@SomeString", DbType.String, SomeString ?? DBNull.Value); // <-- Throws compilation error!
NewDatabase.AddInParameter(NewCommand, "@SomeString", DbType.String, (object)(SomeString) ?? DBNull.Value); // <-- Compiles!
```

I tried other nullable types such as `byte?` and got the same result. Can anyone please tell me why do I need to cast to object first?

Comment: Which exactly is the compilation error? What is the signature of `NewDatabase.AddInParameter`?

Comment: The signature is `void AddInParameter(DbCommand, string, DBType, object)`. The compilation error is "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'".

Comment: Related Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698421/is-if-condition-better-than-and-casting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler what type to use. The result type of the null coalescing operator has to be the same as *one* of the operand types (or the underlying type of the first operand, if it's a nullable value type, in some cases). It doesn't try to find a "most specific type which both operands can be converted to" or anything like that.

For the details of how the language is defined when it comes to the null coalescing operator, see the [C# 4 language specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc), section 7.13:

> The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is `A0`, `A`, or `B`, where `A` is the type of `a` (provided that a has a type), `B` is the type of `b` (provided that `b` has a type), and `A0` is the underlying type of `A` if `A` is a nullable type, or `A` otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

The first example fails because `SomeString` and `DBValue.Null` are not [implicitly interchangable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

That is because the type on the right-hand side of the null-coalescing operator must be implicitly convertible to the type on the left hand side (or vice versa). For your first example, the types involved are `string` and `DBNull`. These types are unrelated, so conversion fails.

Comment: The conversion can work the other way round as well - from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

DBValue.Null is not a string; it's an Object. .NET will not implicitly cast to Object in expressions; it must be explicitly told that you are expecting an Object result.

Answer (score 2):

Because the expression needs to have a single return type. Since `String` and `DbValue` can't be cast to one another, the compiler can't figure out which type return do you want. When you cast to Object, you're giving the compiler a type it can cast to.