# Is “If” condition better than ?? and casting

Tags: c#, performance, casting, null-coalescing-operator

I have following two approaches for same functionality - one with "if” condition and one with  "?? and casting". Which approach is better? Why?

Code:

```
  Int16? reportID2 = null;
  //Other code

  //Approach 1
  if (reportID2 == null)
  {
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report_type_code", DBNull.Value);
  }
  else
  {
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report_type_code", reportID2);
  }

  //Approach 2
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report_type_code", ((object) reportID2) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the answers, following are the benefits of  `??`

1. Increased readability
2. Decreased branching deapth  of program flow (reduced cyclomatic complexity)

Note: Cost of casting as object is negligible.

**REFERENCE**

1. [Null-Coallescing Operator - Why Casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333216/null-coallescing-operator-why-casting?rq=1)

Comment: I would leave `null-col-op`, `performance` and `casting` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) in such cases:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value ?? DBNull.Value);

command.ExecuteScalar() as int? ?? -1;
```

etc.

It increases code readability, decreases branching depth. Also was created especially for database-related scenarios such as ADO.NET.

Comment: Why do you think that is better?

Comment: Why does that compile? Wouldn't `??` complain about incompatible types on both sides?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Sure, it will not. I just left for better readability.

Comment: Doesn't this approach cause a casting as `object`? Doesn't it decrease performance?

Comment: Since the whole idea here is to compare readability of different approaches, leaving the cast out doesn't make it a fair comparison.

Comment: Also I'm not sure that casting to object costs anything.

Comment: @Lijo 1) Since `AddWithValue` takes `object` it always causes boxing, so your approach doesn't save anything. Either way you get one boxing operation per parameter. The cast to object is not free, since the object needs to be collected later on, but it's not too expensive either. 2) A few boxes are negligible compared to the cost of a database query.

Comment: @CodesInChaos whole idea here is NOT only about "compare readability".

Comment: @Lijo About what else? There is no other difference but coding style between your two approaches. So only readability, maintainability, etc. matter, and those are very related concepts.

Comment: Can you please add following two points to your answer if you think they are correct? 1) AddWithValue takes object it always causes boxing 2) Casting to object is not costly.

Answer (score 10):

The null coalescing operator (`??`) is a better approach because it does the same thing as your initial block but in a single, easy to read line. *This makes the code more readable and more maintainable.*

This is one of many examples of syntactic sugar, that is to say code statements which are "shortcuts" for representing a commonly-used idea.`i++` is another example of this, as it replaces `i = i + 1`. It is cleaner and simpler, just like `??`.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong, a switch is a jump table not a simple if! That's the reason there are only simple values allowed.

Comment: @FelixK.: For switch-case less than 4 - it is just if-else (unwrapped by by compiler)

Comment: @FelixK. IMO that's just an implementation detail. The compiler is allowed to turn multiple `if`s into a jump table, and a switch into multiple `if`s.

Comment: @FelixK. - I actually changed the example before I read your comment because I figured `i++` was a simpler comparison more alike to `??` -- hopefully this is less "controversial".

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are right, but in the most cases when you need a switch ( a.e. make a switch on a enum ) they should create a jump table behind it which is faster depending on the implementation ( I don't think the implementation is too bad ). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement

Comment: @FelixK. - I'm speaking out of ignorance here, but wouldn't the decomposition of a `switch` be specific to the compiler of the concerned language?

Comment: @LeviBotelho Right it depends on the compiler but it's anyway wrong to say it's syntactic sugar because in the most cases it is not ( IMHO ). Anyway it's not wrong to say that it might be converted to a if if the compiler think it's useful but in the context of the question it's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, approach 2 is better. You [should not repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and apprach 1 has the code and the parameter name twice. If you want to change the paramater name, you should do so on two places, and this is a hassle.

The real code to compare this to is this:

```
object value = DBNull.Value;
if (reportID2 != null)
{
    value = reportID2;
}
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report_type_code", value);
```

If you use this or the `??` operator is a matter of personal preference. I think the `if` is more clear, especially because you need parenthesis and casting in the case of the coalesce operator.

Comment: No. You should not worry about performance in this case. The difference is negligible.

Comment: Can you improve your answer with following details if you agree?  1) Approach 2 is more readable 2)  AddWithValue always causes boxing as object 3) Casting to object is not costly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the `??` operator. Although brevity does not always lead to better readability, in this case it does because as a reader you don't have to compare what is equal and what is different between the two lines of the `if` and `else`. Furthermore, you eliminated duplication of code (which is always good!). Consider the case you rename your database field name `@report_type_code`. Then you only have to alter it at one place.